# How to select which application should be used by open containing folder?

Tags: firefox, kubuntu, 14.04

I have already read some questions and answers here and on the internet, but I wasn't able to solve my problem. I think it is related to having installed *both* `ubuntu-desktop` and `kubuntu-desktop`.

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop **and** also `kubuntu-desktop`. I mostly use the KDE sessions and hence I'd like all default applications to use KDE's programs, at the very least when running a KDE session.

Currently when I try to open a folder via Firefox's *Open containing folder...* Ubuntu's File application is launched. I'd like to see Dolphin instead.

I thought that firefox used `xdg-open` to open external files but this doesn't seem the case since:

```
xdg-open ~
```

Opens `Dolphin` in a KDE session.

In summary:

How can you **specify exactly** which application is used when clicking on *Open containing folder...*?

**Note 1**:

I have already set `Dolphin` as default:

```
$xdg-mime query default inode/directory
dolphin.desktop
$cat /usr/share/applications/defaults.list | grep inode
inode/directory=kde4/dolphin.desktop
```

Also in system preferences I have selected `Dolphin` as default file manager.

**Note 2**:

I have already tried to reinstall firefox in a KDE session (hoping this would trigger some re-configuration):

```
sudo apt-get remove firefox
sudo apt-get purge firefox
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

this doesn't change anything.

**Note 3**: I noticed the `mimeinfo.cache` file which contains:

```
cat /usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache.backup | grep inode
inode/directory=nautilus-folder-handler.desktop;baobab.desktop;kde4-dolphin.desktop;kde4-gwenview.desktop;kde4-kdesvn.desktop;nautilus.desktop;
```

However I have tried `mv`ing it (and restarting), but nothing changed. I have tried to replace the above line with:

```
inode/directory=kde4-dolphin.desktop;kde4-gwenview.desktop;kde4-kdesvn.desktop;nautilus.desktop;
```

But nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm use `kde-standard` over `ubuntu-desktop`, but my fix to this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1312135) must work with `kde-full` and `kubuntu-desktop` over `ubuntu-desktop` too. Follow this steps:

1. Rename `nautilus`:

   ```
   $ sudo mv /usr/bin/nautilus /usr/bin/nautilus.ubuntu
   ```
2. Create a `nautilus` script in `/usr/local/bin/` with the following content:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   if [ '$KDE_FULL_SESSION' == 'true' ]; then
     if [ '${1}' == '--no-desktop' ]; then shift; fi
     /usr/bin/dolphin "$@"
   else
     /usr/bin/nautilus.ubuntu "$@"
   fi
   ```

That's all! Maybe you have to kill all previous instances of `nautilus` using `killall nautilus` one more time.

**NOTE:** I'm like the K Desktop Environment but I have to develop GTK programs: keeping the Unity desktop intact for debugging is a natural choice for me. My script allows launch both, Dolphin on KDE and Nautilus on Unity, without removing the last one with `sudo apt-get purge nautilus`, but I have to repeat this steps manually if the Nautilus deb package receives an update.